# sequelize.query() returns same result twice

Tags: json, node.js, npm, sequelize.js

I am working in nodejs project in that using `sequelize` for connecting mysql database. I am also using [sequelize-values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-values) for getting raw data from Sequelize instances.

I have written below code

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
require('sequelize-values')(Sequelize);
var sequelizeObj = new Sequelize('mysql://root:@localhost/database');

sequelizeObj.authenticate().then(function (errors) {
    console.log(errors)
});

sequelizeObj.query("SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE `id` = 1200").then(function (result) {

    });
```

Now the table `reports` have only 1 record for `id` 1200, But the `result` gives two objects for same records, Means both records are same of id 1200.

```
[ [ { id: 1200,
  productivity_id: 9969,
  gross_percentage_points: 100 } ],
[ { id: 1200,
  productivity_id: 9969,
  gross_percentage_points: 100 } ] ]
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The first object is the result object, the second is the metadata object (containing affected rows etc) - but in mysql, those two are equal.

Passing `{ type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }` as the second argument will give you a single result object (metadata object omitted

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0#changes-to-raw-query

Comment: const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');

var queryString = "SELECT id from users";
const userList = await Sequelize.query(queryString, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });

Answer (score 9):

Try :

```
sequelizeObj.query("SELECT * FROM `reports` WHERE `id` = 1200", { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(function (result) {
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `{ type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }` as the second argument, also remember to import Sequelize first.

Answer (score -2):

**RESOLVED**

```
sequelize.query("SELECT ...", { type: Sequelize.SELECT })
.then(result => {
    if (!result ) {
        res.status(404).send({ message: "Data Not found." });
    }

    res.status(200).send(result[0]);

})
.catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
});
```