# Sequelize transaction not returning results of promise chain properly

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm running nodeJS and Sequelize (with MSSQL) and am using a transaction that looks like this:

```
app.post('/getOne', ({body}, res) => {
    return sequelize.transaction(t => {
        return getOneStudent(body.id, {transaction: t})
        .then(student => {
            if (student != null){
                return getStudentsGuardians(student.id, {transaction: t})
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {throw new Error(error)})
    })
    .then(result => res.status(200).send({
        studentValues: result,
        success: true,
        })
    )
    .catch(error => res.status(400).send({
        response: error,
        success: false
    }))
})
```

Both the functions `getOneStudent` and `getStudentsGuardians` are Sequelize functions that return promises.

The first should return the student object from the database and the latter should return a json list of the IDs of the student's guardians... for whatever reason it's returning this:

```
{
    "studentValues": [
        [
            {
                "user_id": 1
            },
            {
                "user_id": 2
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "user_id": 1
            },
            {
                "user_id": 2
            }
        ]
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

Here are getOneStudent and getStudentsGuardians:

```
function getOneStudent(id) {
    return models.Student.findByPk(id)
}

function getStudentsGuardians(id){
    return sequelize.query('SELECT user_id FROM Guardians WHERE student_id = ' + id)
}
```

If I remove either return statement, it still get's a success: true but no studentValues. Any idea why I can't get the return value from getOneStudent to resolve in the promise chain?

Comment: What do `getOneStudent ` and `getStudentsGuardians` look like?

Comment: Turns out that it is answered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232147/sequelize-query-returns-same-result-twice